# Права доступа на сайте

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Какие есть способы осуществления прав доступа на сайте и какой из них лучше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Макс Кожанов](/users/6332/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2). Посмотрите в сторону использования [Zend_Acl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/ru/zend.acl.html). Он многим сослужил хорошую службу. (прошу прощения за тавтологию) Да и по сей день служит. Если не используете ZendFramework - не пугайтесь. Его отдельные компоненты достаточно просто интегрировать в свой проект. Успехов Вам!

Answer (score -1):

По мне, так лучше сделать все ручками, а не пользоваться всякими Framework, конечно же если немного знать php и mysql.

Comment: чего тогда на ассемблере сайты не писать ?

Comment: лучше придерживаться золотой середины. с одной стороны нет смысла пихать в проект кучу фреймворков и библиотек, которые могут выполнять всего одну операцию, но с другой стороны специализированные и сложные вещи проще и быстрее реализовать через уже написанный другими код. в идеале чужой код постепенно переваривается под собственный проект и становится его органичной частью.